# Thanks to the newly (purchasing/ purchased) printer,

Tags: participles, modifiers

Which answer is correct in this sentence?

> Thanks to the newly (purchasing/ purchased) printer, we now have fewer problems.

I think the answer is **purchased** because I think it means the printer was recently purchased but my teacher's answer is **purchasing** and I have no chance to ask for explanation.

Comment: Purchased is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"**purchased**" is correct. It refers to an action that has been completed - *The printer has been/was purchased.*

The continuous tense can't be used in this context - "**a purchasing printer**" is the one doing the action here, which means that the printer is purchasing something. This makes no sense unless the printer has some kind of AI inbuilt.

Here is an example where the continuous is valid:

- Thanks to the working generator, we now have electricity.